# Strip Javascript Comments in Java/Scala Program

Tags: java, javascript, regex, scala

I'm trying to reliably strip out Javascript multi-line and single-line comments in Java or Scala.  Even if it requires running an external program, that would be OK (but not ideal).  There must be some library or tool to do this.    I've looked at this post:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/removing-comments-in-javascript/

and converted it to Scala.  But his logic is broken in a few different ways.  One problem is that it doesn't properly tell the difference between division and the start of a regex.  It also doesn't handle escape sequences in all situations.  I've been trying to fix this code, but its tricky - especially telling the difference between regex and division.

I don't want to re-invent the wheel here, and I don't want to build a freaking Javascript parser.  Any ideas?

Comment: sample input and output would be helpful

Comment: You have two comment cases, i.e., `//` for single-line and `/*...*/` for multi-line, right?  Using a sub-string search function for these three specific patterns may be your best bet...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by input and output.  Input would be any possible Javascript.  Output would be that same text, but with all comments removed...

Comment: @abiessu, I think that over-simplifies things because you could be inside of a string or a regex literal

Comment: Have you considered using a Regex strip that would move something along the lines of `/** etc etc**/` and `// etc etc \n`

Comment: But once you have identified all occurrences of `//,/*,*/` then you can decide whether any particular one of them is inside one of those constructs, right?  Do you have statistics on how many times these three patterns occur inside regexp or string literals in your file set?

Answer (score 2):

I think there should be a tool to help you with that but as another option you can use a regex like this:

```
//.*|/\*[\S\s]+?\*/
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/pO7jM3/2)**

[image]

Comment: What if there is a line like this in the code?:
`console.log('Comments in javascript are denoted by //comment text here')`